# Should the time sections in the moderator tools be reversed to match the user section?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, 10k-tools

Recently in an update (I don't know when) I noticed that the time section in the users section had been reversed so it is now in ascending order:

[image]

However, only this list of times was reversed. The one in the tools section is in descending order:

[image]

**Would it not make sense to reverse this too to make them match?**

(This is network wide — not site specific)

Comment: I know this isn't vitally important to anything, but I'm pedantic so I notice these things :)